# how to give permissions to postgres_exporter user with ansible?

Tags: postgresql, ansible, metrics

I need to give some rights to my user postgres_exporter to scrape metrics from postgres to grafana

I can do that on each server by

```
sudo -iu postgres psql -c 'GRANT pg_read_all_settings TO postgres_exporter;'
sudo -iu postgres psql -c  'GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_ls_logdir() TO postgres_exporter;'
sudo -iu postgres psql -c  'GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_ls_waldir() TO postgres_exporter;'
sudo -iu postgres psql -c 'GRANT CREATE ON TABLESPACE pg_global TO postgres_exporter;'
```

But i want to use ansible for that, but without module **postgresql_query**, because its not supporting check diff mode

How to add user to default roles such as **pg_read_all_settings**, without creating a user?

For the last three commands i did, but im not sure about that.

```
- name: GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_ls_logdir() TO postgres_exporter
  community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
    db: "{{ db_name }}"
    port: "{{ pg_port }}"
    privs: EXECUTE
    type: function
    obj: pg_ls_logdir()
    roles: "{{ postgres_exporter_user }}"

- name: GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_ls_waldir() TO postgres_exporter
  community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
    db: "{{ db_name }}"
    port: "{{ pg_port }}"
    privs: EXECUTE
    type: function
    obj: pg_ls_waldir()
    roles: "{{ postgres_exporter_user }}"

- name: GRANT CREATE ON TABLESPACE pg_global TO postgres_exporter
  community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
    db: "{{ db_name }}"
    port: "{{ pg_port }}"
    privs: CREATE
    type: tablespace
    objs: pg_global
    roles: "{{ postgres_exporter_user }}"
```

Comment: I think i can use only **pg_monitor** role instead first 3 commands

Answer (score 0):

role pg_monitor resolve all problems with scraping metrics

```
- name: Grant role pg_monitor to postgres_exporter user
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
  community.postgresql.postgresql_membership:
    group: pg_monitor
    target_roles: "{{ postgres_exporter_user }}"
    state: present
```